# What is the proper way to add an additional parameter to the Login Action in Account Controller in asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

The Login Action:

```
// GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

I have a form in my View:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("RateRestaurant", "Restaurants", new { restaurantId = Model.Restaurant.Id }))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewRate)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewRate, new SelectList(Model.RatesForDropDownList))
            <button type="submit">Rate</button>
        </div>
    }
```

which calls `RateRestaurant` Action:

```
[Authorize]    
public ActionResult RateRestaurant(int newRate, int restaurantId)
{
    var stringUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var userId = new Guid(stringUserId);
    var rate = new Rate() { Rating = newRate, UserId = userId, RestaurantId = restaurantId };

    _context.Ratings.Add(rate);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Restaurants", new { id = restaurantId });
}
```

When I call `RateRestaurant` as a not logged in user, framework calls `Login` Action which takes only `returnUrl` parameter. At the end of login in process it will redirect me to the `returnUrl` which in this case will be `/Resaurants/RateRestaurant?restaurantId=7` but RateRestaurant needs a second argument `NewRate` but in this case it is null. So is there a good way of adding additional parameter that would hold objects like `NewRate` to pass them to the called action?

Comment: it will load the dropdown with default value and user will have to select from it

Answer (score 0):

You could change your form to use the GET method. This way, your `newRate` parameter will be part of the url, so you will also be redirected there after logging in.